# Element type is invalid: expected a string/class/function got: object

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on React-Native project and got problem while trying to implement react-navigation.
I followed a tutorial and when trying to run the project, I get an error that say:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it’s defined in.
```

I searched the web, including this site but couldn't find any solution.
This is my code:
index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Stack } from './config/Router';

class Application extends Component{
  render(){
    <View>
      return <Stack />;
    </View>
  }
}

export default Application;
```

This is the Router:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Login from '../components/Login';
import Home from '../components/Home';

export const Stack = StackNavigator({
  Login:{
    screen: Login
  },
  Home:{
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Home'
    }
  }
});
```

and this is index.ios.js:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Application from './index'

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Application', () => Application);
```

How can I fix the error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like

```js
class Application extends Component{
  render(){
    <View>
      return <Stack />;
    </View>
  }
}
```

should be

```js
class Application extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Stack />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Also you will need to import the `View` component in index.js

`You likely forgot to export your component from the file it’s defined in.`

This is almost always the reason you will get an invalid element error so always double check your imports.

Comment: @JohnDoah You probably need to import the `View` component in index.js